# RDLC page width and e.g. line length

Tags: reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a RDLC report.

- The **page** is **`21cm`** wide with `1cm` margins on both sides (which leaves us **`19cm`** for contents).
- The **body** of the report is **`18.96cm`** wide
- There is a **line** element inside the report with `Location = (0cm; 0cm)` and `EndPoint = (18.95cm, 0cm)` thus the length is **`18.95cm`**. This is like a horizontal separator line inside the report.

So, as you see the body should be enough to contain the line (19cm > 18.96cm > 18.95cm). But when I go and display the report in the ReportViewer/**PrintLayout** control the line actually generates an additional page (because it grows wider for some reason). **And this shows up on the actual printed document (if you print it out).**

Just in case - the simple view in ReportViewer and the exported report both look fine, no additional pages present.

Please tell me - how does this happen and if there are any workarounds to get a good PrintLayout view inside the ReportViewer control? I do not care about the PrintLayout view itself, but I care about printing the document out, which uses the same PrintLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is a strange scenario. Try giving a tolerance of 5mm (0.5cm) instead and let's see what happens.

In other words set the following

- Body: `18.5cm`
- Line: `Location = (0.25cm; 0cm)` and `End Point = (18.0cm; 0cm)`

If that doesn't work, it probably means your page is taller than the size of paper you desire to print on.

A4 is `21cm x 29.7cm` so make sure the height of your body is less than `29.7cm`. If you have top and bottom margins, you'll have to subtract their values as well so the maximum height will be given as follows:

> `Max Height = 29.7 - (Top Margin Height + Bottom Margin Height +` **`tolerance`**)
>
> **`tolerance`** value should be approximately `0.5cm`

Comment: Actually, I found two problems - the 1st problem is that someone committed code to SVN that had hardcoded page margins in it (for the ReportViewer, but fixing that did not fix the problem completely) and the second is the problem that you talk about - for some reason I had to increase the tolerance and the whole thing stopped breaking. So thanks for pointing me to the right direction!